# Staying flexible in the level of detail?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm building a simple scene with lots of cylinders (tubes) that I might want to 3d-print later on. Now I'm wondering how to retain some flexibility when it comes to the resolution, i.e. the number of vertices used to construct one cylinder.
If I use to many, the performance suffers and if I use to few, it might not be possible to easily recover the roundness later on after I used boolean modifiers, I guess.

What's the usual process with Blender and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

While you're indecisive regarding the required resolution of your mesh you could use a *[sub division surface modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf)*

[image]

On cylinders you would need to add support loops to avoid distorsion of the mesh. You could can be add the support loops by selecting both edge-rings and bevel (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>). Alternatively to the support loops you could try an *Edge split modifier*